# How do I send a message in an Spring ApplicationListener (SessionConnectedEvent)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, sockjs, spring-messaging, stompjs

I'm using Stomp over SockJS with Spring messaging. I'm trying to send a message to all logged in users when a new user is connected. So first off here's my listener:

```
@Component
public class SessionConnectedListener implements ApplicationListener<SessionConnectedEvent> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SessionConnectedListener.class);

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionConnectedEvent event) {
        log.info(event.toString());

        // Not sure if it's sending...?
        template.convertAndSend("/topic/login", "New user logged in");
    }

}
```

My WebSocket configurations

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("chat").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

}
```

My JS config

```
var socket = new SockJS('/chat');
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

stompClient.connect({}}, function(frame) {

    // ... other working subscriptions

    stompClient.subscribe("/topic/login", function(message) {
        console.log(message.body);
    });

});
```

My problem here is that my **template.convertAndSend()** doesn't work in the **ApplicationListener**. However, if I put it in a Controller method annotated with @MessageMapping, it will work and I will have a console log client side.

So my question is : Can **template.convertAndSend()** work in an **ApplicationListener**? If so, how? or am I missing something?

Thanks for the help!

PS : my **log.info(event.toString()); works in the ApplicationListener** so I know I'm getting into the onApplicationEvent() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! So weird as it may be, I had my Listener in the following package:

`package my.company.listener;`

But because of a configuration I have in my App context, the **convertAndSend()** method wasn't working.

`@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "my.company" }, excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = { "my.company.web.*" }))`

However when I moved my Listener (Annotated with @Component) to the *web* sub-package, it worked!

`package my.company.web.listener;`

Answer (score 0):

Sending messages with the template within an `ApplicationListener` should work. Please check this [Spring WebSocket Chat](https://github.com/salmar/spring-websocket-chat) sample for an example.

Comment: Yes I know, I followed your sample actually but my subscription isn't catching the message sent through an ApplicationListener.